# Connecting to Snowflake from Databricks through SSO

Tags: single-sign-on, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, databricks, azure-databricks

We are currently planning to use Databricks as compute platform and Snowflake as our DWH system. We have planned to use SSO-based login for both, with our corporate ADFS as the IdP and we are still in the planning phase.

Wanted to check if having SSO enabled at Snowflake will restrict our ability to run jobs on Databricks that interacts with Snowflake for reading/writing data. If yes, what are our alternatives for better login security?

If this set-up is actually possible, can someone please point to any documentation talking about connecting to Snowflake from Databricks through SSO. Didn't really find anything on the topic. The document below mentions that MFA, SSO or any browser based login won't work with Snowflake's Spark connector, not sure if that's relevant to this use case.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/spark-connector-use.html#authenticating-through-a-browser-is-not-supported

Answer (score 0):

For Spark connector use OAuth for authentication.
It can be configured with Microsoft Azure AD, see [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/oauth-azure.html)